# Unicode::GCString error-message: "new: Unicode string must be given"

Tags: perl, unicode

What could here be wrong: I get the error-message
`new: Unicode string must be given at ...`
for the line
`$gvalue = Unicode::GCString->new( $value );`

```
use Unicode::GCString;

# ....
# ....

my $width = 0;
my $gvalue;

if ( $value ) {
    $gvalue = Unicode::GCString->new( $value );
    $width = $gvalue->columns();
}

# ....
# new: Unicode string must be given. at ...
```

---

`$values` comes form:

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#$ref ) {
    for my $j ( 0 .. $#{$ref->[$i]} ) {
        my $value = $ref->[$i][$j] // '';
        # ...
```

Until now while testing `$ref` is hardcoded in script but then it should become a module and `$ref` should be shifted in a routine.

Comment: I tried to look for the error-message in the Unicode::GCString module, but the error-message was in a binary file.

Comment: Okay, how does ref get its values? I'm actually trying to trace back to the original data to see if you have a problem somewhere else. That's why I always recommend people provide complete sample programs and input that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode::GCString suffers from the Unicode Bug (assigns meaning to the UTF8 flag):

```
 $ perl -MUnicode::GCString -E'
    $_=chr(0xE9);
    utf8::downgrade($_);
    Unicode::GCString->new($_);
    say "ok";
 '
 new: Unicode string must be given. at -e line 4.

 $ perl -MUnicode::GCString -E'
    $_=chr(0xE9);
    utf8::upgrade($_);
    Unicode::GCString->new($_);
    say "ok";
 '
 ok
```

It expects a string in stored using the UTF8=1 internal storage format. You can force the string to the right format using `utf8::upgrade`, but it could also be a sign that you forgot to decode the string.

Comment: I believe that this is fixed in the current release.

Comment: @tchirst, I have the latest (Unicode::UCString 2011.03 from NEZUMI/Unicode-LineBreak-2012.02.tar.gz). Also tried with latest dev release (NEZUMI/Unicode-LineBreak-2012.001_29.tar.gz).

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to set `use utf8` (and I had to stringify explicitly `$gstring->as_string`).

Comment: Always start with `use utf8` for utf8 literals and identifiers.