# Unicode::GCString and UTF8 flag

Tags: perl, unicode, string-length

Does this have by design this way that [Unicode::GCString](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3A%3AGCString) assigns meaning to the UTF8 flag ([accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390884/unicodegcstring-error-message-new-unicode-string-must-be-given)) or could this change in a future release?

Comment: Did you just ask if a bug might be fixed in a future release?

Comment: The workaround (`utf8::upgrade($_)`) will work even if the bug is fixed.

Comment: With `utf8::upgrade($_)` `Unicode::GCString` doesn't croak any more if the string is not decoded.

Comment: There's no way to tell if it's been decoded or not. It makes not croak, period.

Comment: Without the work around, GCString croaks for some decoded strings and doesn't croak for some encoded strings. That's why it's a bug.